# Akka-Quartz-Scheduler, how to use cron expression

Tags: scala, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

When i use jobs and triggers to schedule message publishing, it works

```
 val job = JobBuilder.newJob(classOf[ScheduledMessagePublisher]).withIdentity("Job", "Group").build()
                  val trigger: CronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("Trigger", "Group")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 33 10 11 JAN ? 2019"))
                    .forJob("Job", "Group")
                    .build
                  quartz.start()
                  quartz.scheduleJob(job, trigger)
```

But, when i use actors and QuartzSchedulerExtension, my code never fire when the time has come, logs just write `batch acquisition of 0 triggers`

```
val test = context.actorOf(Executor.props(client))
      QuartzSchedulerExtension(context.system).createSchedule("Test", None, "0 33 10 11 JAN ? 2019")
      QuartzSchedulerExtension(context.system).schedule("Test", test, Executor.PublishMessage)
```

i think problem in cron expression `"0 33 10 11 JAN ? 2019"` because when i use only seconds and minutes, it works `"0 30 * * * ? *"`

Comment: here [link](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) you can calculate the right crone expression.. and test again.

Comment: my crone expression configured by right way, because in case with using triggers, cron expression works correctly, byt same cron expression with using actors doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Your `cron` expression is correct.

But the default timezone for `QuartzSchedulerExtension` is **UTC**. Check the document [here](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler#configuration-of-quartz-scheduler).

Hence, you explicitly need to specify your current timezone.
Here's the solution:

```
val test = context.actorOf(Executor.props(client))
  QuartzSchedulerExtension(context.system).createSchedule("Test", None, "0 33 10 11 JAN ? 2019", None, TimeZone.getDefault)
  QuartzSchedulerExtension(context.system).schedule("Test", test, Executor.PublishMessage)
```